# valgrind alters binary behaviour

Tags: c++, valgrind

I try to track down a memory leak in a c++ program using valgrind. The program is compiled with g++ and can be run without throwing any errors. Unfortunately valgrind alters the behaviour of my program in a way that it crashes after throwing a runtime-error. As this crash happens before reaching the relevant parts of the code, I have no chance to track down my memory leak.

The whole problem is illustrated by the attached console output.

```
myUser@computer:~$ ./myProgram input.xml

Processing...

Finished successfully...

----------------------
Hit Enter to continue...

myUser@computer:~$ valgrind --leak-check=yes --log-file=valgrindLog ./myProgram input.xml

Processing...
myProgram-error: Not working Polymorphism. Base class method called instead of derived class method. End-of-myProgram-error.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted
myUser@computer:~$ g++ -dumpversion
4.4.5
myUser@computer:~$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian
myUser@computer:~$ uname -r
2.6.35-30-generic
myUser@computer:~$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
```

Comment: I doubt that valgrind alters the behaviour of your program, I merely think that your program somehow exhibits UB, and just the symptoms are different. Have you bothered looking at the valgrind log for errors?

Comment: Well, valgrind hooks memory allocation functions, so it indeed modifies the program behavior. However the program should not care and it it does care it means it has some UB that is exhibited by valgrind.

Comment: @sharptooth somehow I doubt that the problem is in the valgrind without seeing the code

Comment: @VJovic: The problem is not in valgrind, just valgring kicking in exposes it.

Comment: Is anything interesting in the valgrind log? Look, maybe there's something to fix.

Comment: @sharptooth ok, sorry. I misunderstood your comment. I agree that most likely this is a cause of an UB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that valgrind is changing the behavior of your code because you have a bug more serious than a memory leak.  Bug free, portable code probably won't throw exceptions just because you run it with valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues where Valgrind's mucking about in everything exposes thread contention issues that previously never arose.  I don't suppose something of the sort could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately valgrind alters the behaviour of my program in a way that it crashes after throwing a runtime-error. As this crash happens before reaching the relevant parts of the code, I have no chance to track down my memory leak.

This is *great* luck. Now in addition to finding and fixing the memory leak, you can find and fix a bug too. Have you looked at the core file to find out where your code faulted?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all of you!!!

I have returned to my code to trace down the undefined behaviour, which valgrind had revealed. Finally I've found it and could improve my code by that.

Once again thank you very much!!